# R: local ranking lists, aggregated by value in row

Tags: r, subset, ranking

I have data of the following form:

```
"almond" "blueberry" 3
"almond" "leek" 6
"almond" "citron" 7
"almond" "fish" 2
...
"leek" "swiss_cheese" 3
"leek" "pumpkin" 5
"leek" "onion" 4
"leek" "chocolate" 10
...
```

For each value in the first column I want to find the *k* best partners according to the third column. "Best" means: lower number in the third row. Thus, for *almond* its three best partners are *fish, blueberry, leek*. For *leek*, its three best partners are *`swiss_cheese`, onion, and pumpkin*. I finally want to reduce the full table to the three best partners for each of the factors in the first column, i.e.

```
"almond" "blueberry" 3
"almond" "leek" 6
"almond" "fish" 2
...
"leek" "swiss_cheese" 3
"leek" "pumpkin" 5
"leek" "onion" 4
...
```

Comment: I suggest you provide an example data set and the answer you want.  Then maybe somebody can provide the R code needed to convert the example data set into the desired answer.

Comment: For tips on making it easier for people to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Dason, I read most of this. Still, I do not see what is lacking to answer this specific example. There is a sample data set and a wanted result. Can you help me finding the weak spot? Obviously, for me, my question is clear ;-)

Comment: Your example data is just some strings on a page. It is not clear they are in a `data.frame` or what kind of object. The first three (and more) answers to the linked FAQ show how to recreate example data sets as part of a question

Answer (score 0):

So, one way I found to do that is

```
require(plyr)
t <- ddply(table, .(V1), transform, rank = rank(V3))
z <- t[rank <= k,]
```

The first row loads the package if not already done so. The second adds a last column to *table* which is called *rank* and contains the rank of each row according to the third column ("V3"), aggreated by the first column ("V1"). I.e., for each distinct value in the first column, there is a local ranking of all rows containint it. In the second step I can then subset only those rows in which the rank is smaller than the given *k*.